Adding pip to Yocto
I need to use pip in a custom recipe and decided to create a python3-pip for it seeing as yocto was throwing an error due to it missing. This is the current file I have:
DESCRIPTION = "Python package installer for Python 3"
HOMEPAGE = "https://pypi.org/project/pip/"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=63ec52baf95163b597008bb46db68030"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/pypa/pip.git;branch=main;protocol=https;name=pip"
SRCREV_pip = "97146c7f4cd85551f3dc261830a57f304e43c181"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit /opt/yocto/imx-5.15.71-2.2.0/kirkstone/sources/poky/meta/classes/setuptools3.bbclass

DEPENDS = "python3-setuptools"

do_compile() {
    cd ${S}
    python3 setup.py build
}

do_install() {
    cd ${S}
    python3 setup.py install --root=${D} --prefix=/usr
}

FILES_${PN} = "${PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES_DIR}"

For some reason, it keeps throwing me an error;
ERROR: python3-pip-1.0-r0 do_compile: ExecutionError('/opt/yocto/imx-5.15.71-2.2.0/kirkstone/bld-xwayland/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/python3-pip/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.368349', 2, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /opt/yocto/imx-5.15.71-2.2.0/kirkstone/bld-xwayland/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/python3-pip/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.368349
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| python3: can't open file '/opt/yocto/imx-5.15.71-2.2.0/kirkstone/bld-xwayland/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/python3-pip/1.0-r0/git/setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
| WARNING: /opt/yocto/imx-5.15.71-2.2.0/kirkstone/bld-xwayland/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/python3-pip/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.368349:152 exit 2 from 'python3 setup.py build'
| WARNING: Backtrace (BB generated script):
|       #1: do_compile, /opt/yocto/imx-5.15.71-2.2.0/kirkstone/bld-xwayland/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/python3-pip/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.368349, line 152
|       #2: main, /opt/yocto/imx-5.15.71-2.2.0/kirkstone/bld-xwayland/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/python3-pip/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.368349, line 156
ERROR: Task (/opt/yocto/imx-5.15.71-2.2.0/kirkstone/sources/meta-custom/recipes-apps/python3-pip/python3-pip.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'#

Initially I didn't have the do_compile() but before asking here tried to get some help but still couldn't manage to get it working. Any advice?
Notes: I'm building this for the following machine: imx8mpevk

Why did you create a python3-pip recipe if it already exists inside openembedded-core? Just add it in IMAGE_INSTALL:append "python3-pip" [1]
And to use pip in a recipe you just need to inherit pip and pass the package name in PYPI_PACKAGE, example: python3-ansi2html_1.7.0.bb
